# store function results into textfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, iteration

I'm struggling with this one. Having a file that detects palindromes I now have a function with which I want to parse through a textfile and if the sentence in that textfile is a palindrome this sentence should be written to a new textfile called palindrome.txt

My code writes the entire textfile into palindrome.txt, how should I rewrite this function?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

let fs = require("fs");
let Phrase = require("mhartl-palindrome");

let text = fs.readFileSync("phrases.txt", "utf-8");
text.split("\n").forEach(function(line) {
  let phrase = new Phrase(line);
  if (phrase.palindrome()) {
    fs.writeFile('palindromes.txt', text, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Text saved!');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: writeFile will replace the existing content, use [fs.appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) to add to the end of a file.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks I just saw your comment. It changes the behaviour as the entire text now gets added to the new textfile for every iteration. I'm working on 10.1.1 it's the first exercise of the chapter: https://www.softcover.io/read/28fdb94f/learn_enough_javascript/shell_scripts

Answer (score 0):

[fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) will override the original content. You need to provide a [Buffer.from(line)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe) to [fs.appendFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_appendfile_data_options). I use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based approach to achieve the desired outcome.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const Phrase = require("mhartl-palindrome");

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const appendFile = util.promisify(fs.appendFile);

(async () => {
    const text = await readFile("phrases.txt", "utf-8");

    await Promise.all([
        text.split("\n").map(async line => {
            const phrase = new Phrase(line);

            if (phrase.palindrome()) {
                await appendFile("palindromes.txt", Buffer.from(line));
                console.log('Text saved!');
            }

            return Promise.resolve();
        })
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: looks good and makes sense, but I get this error:
```
syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
```

Do you know how to get rid of this? It seems to be common with older Unix and Windows systems, but I'm on a mac

Comment: just this: 

➜  js_tutorial ./palindrome_file
./palindrome_file: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./palindrome_file: line 1: `const fs = require("fs");'

Comment: I'm really sorry I can't understand your error.  can you create a codepen? so I can see all your code.

Comment: oh the link seems broken. Let me see

Comment: @a56z I just executed the code & it worked fine, saved the palindromes to the file?

Comment: oh I see, alright then it must be some setting on my mac. It's alright as the concept is clear, thx also for pointing at Buffer.from(line) as I wasn't aware of this :)